# JSX not transpiling with Gulp and Babel

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I have a Gulp script with which I am trying to launch a React application.

- The Gulp file is named `gulpfile.babel.js`
- I am adding the Babel preset 'env' as an option
- There is also a `.babelrc` file in the same directory with the same preset option

The Gulp file includes:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

// convert jsx to JS
gulp.task('babelFiles', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.@(js|jsx)')
        .pipe(babel({
            compact: false,
            presets: ['env'],
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});


// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['babelFiles', 'browserSync']);

// Configure the browserSync task
gulp.task('browserSync', ['babelFiles'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: ''
        },
    })
})
```

When the Gulp task launches I see an error about an unexpected token:

```
  29 |         return (
> 30 |             <div>
     |             ^
```

This tells me something is wrong with the JSX transpilation in the react setup? Would you happen to know what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 1):

`babel-preset-env` does not include a preset to transpile your JSX to plain JavaScript. For that you'll need `babel-preset-react`:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

Then apply it:

```
presets: ['env', 'react']
```

`babel-preset-env` determines which plugins you'll need for your JavaScript, such as plugins for ES2015, 2016, and 2017. It does no, however, account for things such as  JSX.

Comment: It appears that Gulp/Babel is working fine, but the index.js files changes to have syntax for react such as "var _react = require('react');". I then see an error in the console that require is not defined. Does this mean I need to add requireJS to my site? What would be the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: @mm2887 you'll have to use Webpack to package your project for the web.

Comment: is there no way to utilize Gulp to do this? I am basically trying to add React onto a Bootstrap based website which already has a Gulp file with a bunch of working tasks.

Comment: @mm2887 You could use [`gulp-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webpack).

Comment: Thank you - I'll try that out